# QT - Watch typedef anonymous enum local variable

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qt5, typedef

I'm using QT Creator 5.9. I'm unable to watch enum variable which is based on a typedef anonymous enum.

```
typedef enum
{
    enum_val1,
    enum_val2
}en;

en temp_var = enum_val1;
```

If I add temp_var in watch window, it displays '`<no such value>`'.
Is this a bug or is there any settings I have to enable to watch the variable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking at an optimized build? The variable could have been optimized away.

Comment: @StoryTeller I haven't mentioned optimization explicitly any where. Could you please let me know where to check if this is an optimized build? I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm by no means a QT Creator expert. Haven't used it, to be precise. But variables "not existing" in a debugger is universally a sign of debugging an optimized executable. So I suggest you research how optimization settings are set in QT Creator projects, and make sure those are turned off before building the executable you intend to debug.

Comment: This is probably a Qt Creator issue, because Visual Studio 2013 shows the variable just fine. You might want to rewrite the same code differently.

Comment: @vahancho Yes, we have used the same type of code in VS2013 and were able to debug without any issue. That's why I was wondering if it was anything to do with the QT Creator.

Comment: @Gomu, as I said, you could try to declare your enum differently, like `enum class en { enum_val1, enum_val2 };`

Comment: @vahancho Actually there are lots of enums declared this way. If we could make it as named enum there is no issue. But, it involves lot of effort. That's why I'm trying to do that as last resort if nothing else works.